# How to use BeautifulSoup to scrape links in a html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I need download few links in a html. But I don't need all of them, I only need few of them in certain section on this webpage. 
For example, in http://www.nytimes.com/roomfordebate/2014/09/24/protecting-student-privacy-in-online-learning, I need links in the debaters section. I plan to use BeautifulSoup and I looked the html of one of the links:

```
<a href="/roomfordebate/2014/09/24/protecting-student-privacy-in-online-learning/student-data-collection-is-out-of-control" class="bl-bigger">Data Collection Is Out of Control</a>
```

Here's my code:

```
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
link_set = set()
for link in soup.find_all("a", class = "bl-bigger"):
    href = link.get('href')
    if href == None:
        continue
    elif '/roomfordebate/' in href:
        link_set.add(href)    
for link in link_set:
    print link
```

This code is supposed to give me all the links with bl-bigger class. But it actually returns nothing. Could anyone figure what's wrong with my code or how to make it work?
Thanks

Comment: You will never find it. The link is not in your page_source. Try using selenium or find the right request, r = requests.get(url) with your url wont get you the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see `bl-bigger` class at all when I view the source from Chrome. May be that's why your code is not working?

Lets start looking at the source. The whole Debaters section seems to be put within `div` with class `nytint-discussion-content`. So using BeautifulSoup, lets get that whole `div` first.

```
debaters_div = soup.find('div', class_="nytint-discussion-content")
```

Again learning from the source, seems all the links are within a list, `li` tag. Now all you have to do is, find all `li` tags and find anchor tags within them. One more thing you can notice is, all the `li` tags have class `nytint-bylines-1`.

```
list_items = debaters_div.find_all("li", class_="nytint-bylines-1")
list_items[0].find('a')
# <a href="/roomfordebate/2014/09/24/protecting-student-privacy-in-online-learning/student-data-collection-is-out-of-control">Data Collection Is Out of Control</a>
```

So, your whole code can be:

```
link_set = set()
response = requests.get(url)
html_data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data)
debaters_div = soup.find('div', class_="nytint-discussion-content")
list_items = debaters_div.find_all("li", class_="nytint-bylines-1")

for each_item in list_items:
    html_link = each_item.find('a').get('href')
    if html_link.startswith('/roomfordebate'):
        link_set.add(html_link)
```

Now `link_set` will contain all the links you want. From the link given in question, it will fetch 5 links.

PS: `link_set` contains only uri and not actual html addresses. So I would add `http://www.nytimes.com` at start before adding those links to `link_set`. Just change the last line to:

```
link_set.add('http://www.nytimes.com' + html_link)
```

Comment: you solution seems correct. I did see "bl-bigger" class by using inspect element in google chrome. What's the difference between search in source code versus using inspect element?

Comment: it's same and there is no difference. Inspect lets you target certain div and gives more dev friendly code access. And even I have also used Inspect Element itself.

Comment: I found the answer. They are not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070190/is-the-html-is-view-source-different-from-the-html-in-inspect-element

Comment: I guess, I also learnt something :) However in this case it does not matter in case, as you are not making any changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method with an object instead of keyword argument:

```
soup.find("tagName", { "class" : "cssClass" })
```

or use `.select` method which executes CSS queries:

```
soup.select('a.bl-bigger')
```

Examples [are in the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), just search for '.select' string. Also, instead of writing the entire script you'll quickly get some working code with [ipython](http://ipython.org/) interactive shell.

Comment: None of these approaches work. Did you ever tried in the html I give?

Comment: Well, there was no url at the time I answered it. And the data is coming from Ajax. Open Network tab in Chrome developer tools and see the url it opens, then try opening it and parsing. Good luck.