# Why when downloading html and save it as a file on the hard disk the html file content is not the same as the view-source content?

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms

This is the original html url: http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums2008/forumpage.aspx?forumid=393&pagenumber=1

[Original Link](http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums2008/forumpage.aspx?forumid=393&pagenumber=1)

And this is how i download the html:

```
private void GetHtml()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
            {
                webclient.DownloadFile(sourceUrl + i, combinedHtmlsDir + "\\Page" + i + ".html");
            }
        }
```

And the content i'm getting on saved html file is: this is the top lines of the content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

        <meta name="description" content="פורום מזג האוויר - תפוז פורומים, קהילות בכל נושא שבעולם. בואו לדבר על מזג האוויר במערכת הפורומים הטובה ביותר ברשת." />

        <meta name="keywords" content="פורום, פורומים, קהילות, מאמרים, מידע, דיון, תגובות ,תפוז, תפוז אנשים,מזג האוויר" />
```

And this is the top lines of the page view-source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

        <meta name="description" content="מתעניינים במזג האוויר? רוצים לקבל מידע אונליין על המתרחש? היכנסו לפורום מזג אוויר בתפוז!" />

        <meta name="keywords" content="פורום, פורומים, קהילות, מאמרים, מידע, דיון, תגובות ,תפוז, תפוז אנשים,מזג האוויר, מזג אויר, חיזוי, אקלים, אטמוספירה, גשמים, חום, קור, משקעים, גשם, רוחות, רוח, עננות, עננים, ענן, צירוס, קומולוס, צירוסים, קומולוסים, קרה, ברד, קר, חם, מזג אוויר, לחות, nzd vtuuhr, דני רופ, מטאורולוג" />
```

The content is not the same. How can i download the same content of the view-source ? Could be the link i'm downloading from is different from the view-source one ?

I also tested now if i'm surfing to the website to the page and then making on it right click with the mouse and make save as and save it as: Webpage, HTML Only then it's fine the html file on my hard disk is 311KB size.

But with my program the html file size on the hard disk is only 77KB.

I can't figure out why it's not saving me the same content and size of html file in my program like if i'm doing save as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page is dynamic (content will changes), I suspect your problem is that the content changed between your view source and your download.

If this is not the case avenues to pursue would be, checking if the browser/js changes the DOM tree that you see in your view source, or it's possible that the site changes it's content based on user agent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't download the real source, but an interpreted code.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13070367/4592312 .