# How to get value from dialog in jquery ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have referenced from https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form to create a dialog modal form.

The code has a function to insert new row to table, like this:

```
  if ( valid ) {
    $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
      "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
    "</tr>" );
    dialog.dialog( "close" );
  }
  return valid;
}
```

I don't understand that: After submiting, I viewed page source, no new row was inserted.

Then, I checked it in `Inspector`(Firefox - Ctrl + Shift + C). I saw it. A new row has been inserted.

[image]

Can I `"un-hidden"` it and display on source page?

**UPDATE**

```
      <script>
  $(function() {
    var dialog, form,

      // From http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29
      emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
      name = $( "#name" ),
      email = $( "#email" ),
      password = $( "#password" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function addUser() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      valid = valid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

      valid = valid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter." );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( email, emailRegex, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

      if ( valid ) {
        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
      }
      return valid;
    }

    dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": addUser,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addUser();
    });

    $( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: What does your valid variable return?

Comment: @Mohit It returns `true` (`var valid = true;`). I'm not the author of code. I only reference from the site.

Comment: Okay.Can you also check what css style is applied on <tr>

Comment: @Mohit `div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }` No `<tr>` css was defined

Comment: Are you able to see something on the page If you hover on the dom?Also check your dom structure?

Answer (score 0):

"Page Source" only displays codes which are preloaded based on the original file.

Whereas, "Inspect Element" shows codes that up-to-date with the DOM and all the codes are updated on the fly.

Refer to [Is the HTML is View Source different from the HTML in Inspect Element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070190/is-the-html-is-view-source-different-from-the-html-in-inspect-element)

Answer (score 0):

The source page only shows the content of the file you are viewing. Since JavaScript doesn't edit the file itself those changes can't be seen in the source page but that's what the inspector is for.