# capybara cannot find value on a page

Tags: javascript, capybara

I have a web page game that displays a value in an input field using javascript and jquery. The value I am looking to test is visible on the page. However if I inspect the element, the value does not appear in the html.

Here is some JS code that sets the value:

```
function updateTotal(){
        $('#edit-game-result').val(game.totalScore);
      }
```

And here is the html input field:

```
<input type="text" id="edit-game-result" size="10" maxlength="3" class="form-text" readonly/>
```

I have tried Capybara tests like:

expect(find_field('edit-game-result').value).to eq 10

This test finds the field but gives output: 
expected: 10 got: nil

I think this is somehow due to this: 
[Is the HTML is View Source different from the HTML in Inspect Element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070190/is-the-html-is-view-source-different-from-the-html-in-inspect-element)
but I cannot find a way to make Capybara read the value.

This might be relevant also: 
http://ahmednadar.github.io/12/09/2013/overwrite-how-Capybara-ignores-hidden-elements/

I believe that the field does have a value of 10 when the test is run. However I am not able to access that value in the Capybara test.

Can you help me find a Capybara test that works or shed some light on why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you're finding the element and then checking the value on it which won't wait for the value to match.  Instead you should be using the matchers Capybara provides

```
expect(page).to have_field('edit-game-result', with: '10')
```

which will use Capybaras waiting/retrying behavior to wait until the value is changed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that but got :
`Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_field('edit-game-result', with: '10')
       expected to find field "edit-game-result" with value "10" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.`

Comment: @jeebee Then the field doesn't have the value of '10' within Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds when you check it  or it isn't visible on the page.  You can check for a non-visible element by passing `visible: false` option to `have_field` but you really shouldn't be relying on checking non-visible elements in tests.  Other than that show the rest of your test so we can see what you're actually doing

Comment: Hi Thomas

My code is here:
https://github.com/glynester/bowling-challenge/blob/last_frame/spec/features/game_play_spec.rb
I tried many combinations including adding "visible: false" but it didn't work. I even added 10 seconds wait time in spec_helper.rb for capybara.
Thanks for looking.

Comment: @jeebee You're testing JS behavior, but using the default rack_test driver which doesn't support JS.  See https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#selecting-the-driver

Comment: Hi Thomas
Thanks for that and of course you are right. 
I have now been installing various gems to get this going. The last step (surely) is that I need to add the geckodriver to the system path. I tried this in the command line:
`export PATH=$PATH:/home/glynester/Desktop/Projects/geckodriver`
(as per https://mzl.la/29MCc1e) but rspec still is not working. I get this message:
`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver.`

Comment: I obviously have not set the path right for the driver I downloaded but not sure how to do it. I don't suppose you can see what I've done wrong. Sorry new to Ubuntu, Ruby, JS, etc. :)

Comment: @jeebee  If that folder is where the geckodriver executable is located then it should work (although if you're using selenium-webdriver 3.0 I'd recommend configuring for chrome rather than firefox currently)  One thing to check would be that the the geckodriver executable in the /home/glynester/Desktop/Projects/geckodriver folder is actually executable  (I'm assuming that is a folder and not actually the link to the executable -- the PATH is directories that are searched for the executable)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127477/discussion-between-jeebee-and-thomas-walpole).