# How to Hide The Source

Tags: hide, obfuscation, view-source

Okay, I am not sure if this question belongs here.

Either way, I am interested to know how to show one source on *Developer ➛ Page Source* (Firefox) and totally another when *CTRL+A on the page ➛ Inspect Element*. I have seen it is done on some of the sites I have visited, for instance: `http://www.therigsofficial.com/`

Thank you. I truly appreciate all help.

Comment: The difference is explained here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070190/is-the-html-is-view-source-different-from-the-html-in-inspect-element

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to hide your javascript completley, but you can make it harder to read by obfuscating.
Try this tool [JavaScript Obfuscator. Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tth.JavaScriptObfuscator). It can work on your case.