# AngleSharp: run all JavaScript before looking for element

Tags: javascript, c#, anglesharp

I'm currently building an app for web automation using AngleSharp. I've managed to log in to a website, but can't find the element I'm looking for using context.Active.QuerySelectorAll.

I understand that this is likely because some of the JavaScript hasn't run in the HTML I'm searching through, as per this link: [Is the HTML shown via 'View Source' different from the HTML shown in (Firebug) developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070190/is-the-html-shown-via-view-source-different-from-the-html-shown-in-firebug-d)

How do I force AngleSharp to execute all of the JavaScript before I look for the specific element?

code:

```
var config = AngleSharp.Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCookies().WithJavaScript().WithCss();
            var browsingContext = BrowsingContext.New(config);

            await browsingContext.OpenAsync("https://users.premierleague.com/");
            await browsingContext.Active.QuerySelector<IHtmlFormElement>("form[action='/accounts/login/']").SubmitAsync(new
            {
                login = "abc@gmail.com",
                password = "password"
            });
            await browsingContext.OpenAsync("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/team/my/");
```

Everything works fine up until this point, and I can confirm that I am logged in. However, I then can't seem to get a value returned for the following:

```
var x = browsingContext.Active.QuerySelectorAll("*").Where(m => m.ClassName == "ismjs-link ism-link ism-link--more");
```

And I know that this element exists, as I've checked numerous times through the "Inspect" functionality available on Google Chrome.

What am I missing/ how do I get the JavaScript to run?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that element contained in an iframe?

Comment: Not inside an iframe no. There is however a script in the source that contains the exact variable that I'm looking for. Is there a way to run JavaScript that will return the value of that variable? Variable is called as "player_first_name"

Comment: If its accessible through your console window, you should be able to access it through the script.

Comment: There are two potential issues: 1. The JS is too heavy / advanced for the JS interpreter in AngleSharp (happens often, actually only simple scripts would work quite fine). 2. You run your C# code too early. When you use the query selector all - has some time passed after opening the page? The JS code actually runs asynchronous and is decoupled from the original loading. Usually, it will be done afterwards.

Comment: One of my problems was that the page that I was trying to parse was protected by Cloudflare and the loaded page was saying `Checking if the site connection is secure`. It somehow redirects to the real page later on... You can dump the page content to see what you got : `var doc = await browsingContext.OpenAsync(pageUrl); doc.ToHtml();`.