# Element has ID in inspection mode, but not in raw HTML

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am currently working on a small web scraping script with Python and Selenium.

I am trying to get some information from a table, which has in inspection mode a certain ID. 
However, when I open the page as raw HTML (which I did after not being able to locate that table using neither xpath or css_selector), the table does not have the mentioned ID.

How is that possible?

**For better explanation:**

This is what it looks like in inspection mode in my browser

```html
<table id='ext-gen1076' class='bats-table bats-table--center'>
[...]
</table>
```

And this is what it looks like when I open the page as raw HTML file

```html
<table class='bats-table bats-table--center'>
[...]
</table>
```

How is it possible, that the ID is simply disappearing?
(JFI, this is my first question so apologies for the bad formatting!).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this post its similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070190/is-the-html-shown-via-view-source-different-from-the-html-shown-in-firebug-d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, the ID was added during the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the *id* attribute i.e. **ext-gen1076** contains a number and is clearly dynamically generated. The prefix of the value of the *id* attribute i.e. **ext-gen** indicates that the **id** was generated runtime using **Ext JS**.

---

### Ext JS

[Ext JS](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) is a JavaScript framework for building data-intensive, cross-platform web and mobile applications for any modern device.

---

### This usecase

Possibly you have identified the `<table>` element even before the [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) have rendered the complete [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes). Hence the **id** attribute was missing.

---

### Identifying Ext JS elements

As the value of the *id* attribute changes i.e. dynamic in nature you won't be able to use the complete value of the *id* attribute and can use only partial value which is static. As per the HTML you have provided:

```
<table id='ext-gen1076' class='bats-table bats-table--center'>
[...]
</table>
```

To identify the <`table`> node you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table[id^='ext-gen']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[starts-with(@id,'ext-gen')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

However, there would be a lot other elements with *id* attribute starting with **`ext-gen`**. So to uniquely identify the `<table>` element you need to club up the *class* attribute as follows:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.bats-table.bats-table--center[id^='ext-gen']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='bats-table bats-table--center' and starts-with(@id,'ext-gen')]")))
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to find element by part of its id name in selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637048/how-to-find-element-by-part-of-its-id-name-in-selenium-with-python/59637443#59637443)
- [How to get selectors with dynamic part inside using Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582353/how-to-get-selectors-with-dynamic-part-inside-using-selenium-with-python/49587006#49587006)